# Could I try Ubuntu 14 before permanent install?

Tags: nvidia

I got som problems with my Ubuntu 12 after an update.
The display does not work any more, can not find nvidia-173.

Since there is a 14 out now I wonder if I could create the image on a CD and boot the computer with that to see if everything works before I permanatly install it?

If that is possible, could I also browse the files and create a backup of some files that I have on the computer?

I think I have "home" on one partion and the OS on an other partion that might be crucial if I will do an upgrade-install and still have my files left. But how can I check that before?
Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just burn the Ubuntu image and boot into the live system to test out 14.04 before you install it.
You can check with `lsblk` if your home directory is on a different partition/disk.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it is possible. You can download the Ubuntu 14.04 liveCD from [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop. And then boot up your computer using the liveCD. Choose the option try ubuntu without installing. That would boot from the DVD, and will not make any changes to your PS. After you are happy with all of your tests, you can go ahead and install.
Ubuntu usually works better on older hardware, as the drivers are more likely to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You have a display problem. Updating to 14.04 might solve that problem, and it might not work out. Trying the live cd will show you if 14.04 works with your system. So in that case a clean install will work.

Do you have a complex setup (like for development) or a pretty standard ubuntu (all programs installed via the software center - no complex configuration)? In the former case, you could make an image of you current harddrive, to go back to it. After making that image, make sure you try if it works, otherwise it's a waste of time and effort. Better - if you have a spare disk: use the image to try the upgrade, and keep the original drive as it is.